# What mathematical formula can I use to prove a variable is a whole number?

Tags: math, formula

I want to use a math formula to prove a variable is a whole number and not a decimal or fraction. Do you know of any simple ones that will help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: `if (variable = math.floor(variable))`?

Comment: That could work, but I want something with only math and without programming logic.

Comment: @user3258980, depending on the language it might not be possible to do what you want.

Comment: Floor is hardly programming logic, Gauss introduced it in 1808. Why do you want to do this, and what functions are acceptable to use, which aren't, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Any number you are storing is residing in memory somewhere as binary bits. So you have to store numbers with some sort of encoding. How you then decide if a number is in the set of integers will ultimately depend on how you decided to encode numbers. Different languages have different conventions but I don't see how you can come up with some language agnostic formula as per your comment. Many languages will offer you tools to help deal with various numeric types, I suspect this is the only way to solve your problem.